# .htaccess redirect 500 internal server error wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Hello i am having trouble with .htaccess redirection to my maintenance.html page. Can someone please help me. Here my sample code of .htaccess

```
<Limit GET POST PUT>
 order deny,allow
 deny from all
 allow from 123.456.789
 allow from 123.456.789
</LIMIT>
ErrorDocument 403 /maintenance.html
<Files maintenance.html>
 order allow,deny
 allow from all
</Files>
```

I an having a  500 internal server error.

Comment: Check your apache error_log. http://www.techiecorner.com/97/redirect-to-maintenance-page-during-upgrade-using-htaccess/

Answer (score 0):

You're close. All you need is a condition to prevent redirection if the request is for an image.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=127.0.0.1
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance\.html
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^.*$ http://localhost/blabla/maintenance.html [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me ! Please put maintenance.html in root.

```
##
 # Maintenance page
 ##
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  # local ip
  RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^222.222.333
  # server ip
  RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^111.222.333
  # maintenance page and assets
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif) [NC]
  # serve default 503 response
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ maintenance.html [R=503,L]
 </IfModule>
 # serve custom 503 response
 ErrorDocument 503 /maintenance.html
 <IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header always set Retry-After "86400"
 </IfModule>
```